# Mediawiki Infoboxes CSS

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm new to mediawiki and I'm having trouble in the Infoboxes. I've tried the versions 1.31 and 1.33 but both of them just give the same output. which is like this

[My local infobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqWkO.png)

and I wanted to make it look like this:

[Liquipedia's Infobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiZWm.png)

And also, I've tried [wikipedia's](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_Wikipedia_infoboxes_tutorial) version of inboxes, Used version 1.33, imported all of the needed modules and templates but still get the same output as the 1st image above. Are there any parts I missed? Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the parameters used to display the template and outline exactly what is missing that you expected to see. For instance, we don't know if you have forgotten the parameter to the photo or exactly which template this is (Wikipedia has dozens of player templates). The Import Log would be useful. Your screenshot shows Template:Herostat and its subpages are missing - Wanted Templates may highlight more that you missed. CSS may also be in MediaWiki:Common.css

Answer (score 0):

You imported the required templates, but not the required CSS files. Make sure to import those too.

Comment: I have a concern regarding this called css-sanitizer.  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Css-sanitizer how do I use this, and where should I input the code on my wiki's skin? Isn't the css-sanitizer same package of Extension:TemplateStyles? Sorry, I'm just new to mediawiki so I'm not surprised that I'm missing something.

Comment: Also, there are no such css files on liquipedia's github. I'm really confused because the documentation shown on wikimedia was most likely archived, there are no recent updates for the newest wiki versions.

Comment: css-sanitizer is a library used by TemplateStyles. If you have followed the install instructions of TemplateStyles, you don't need to do anything about it manually. As others have noted, the CSS for a template might come from some generic CSS wiki page such as `MediaWiki:Common.css` as well some wiki page handled by TemplateStyles. It usually does not come from code, so you won't find anything in git.